# How can I read and update the value of a bundled variable in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I created a simple app with Svelte, and I used the bundle files to embed the app into a new web page like the following:

```html
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "https://.../bundle.css">
<script defer src = "https://.../bundle.js"></script>
```

Is it possible in Svelte to make the `bundle.js` reusable so everyone can change the value of a variable for example to update something in the app (without creating a npm package)?

Comment: Look at .env variables. More here: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

You can build the bundle in way that it exports the main component and pass values as properties or [context](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-setcontext). It then can just be imported in an inline `<script>` and parameterized that way:

```html
<script>
  import App from 'https://.../bundle.js';

  new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: { ... },
    context: new Map(...),
  });
</script>
```

Contexts are useful if the variable is deeply nested in the component hierarchy.